# Table with all possible combinations from AA to ZZ

Tags: sql

> The result of this table is currently not managable in SQL and hence I worked with an alternative. Thanks to anyone who looked into this.

---

I am looking to create a table in SQL (Microsoft) with all possible combinations from AA to ZZ including "NULL" so that 'AA' is one of the possible combinations and then 'AA' and 'ZZ' is another combination. I have started with the following but quit at 'AZ' as it got too complex:

```
    with T_VALUE as (
    select 'AA' as Value union
    select 'AB' union
    select 'AC' union
    select 'AD'     )

select  distinct
    Value as Value_1,
    null as Value_2,
    null as Value_3,
    null as Value_4
from    T_VALUE
union
select  A.Value,
    B.Value,
    null,
    null
from    T_VALUE A
    cross join T_VALUE B
where   A.Value < B.Value
union
select  A.Value,
    B.Value,
    C.Value,
    null
from    T_VALUE A
    cross join T_VALUE B
    cross join T_VALUE C
where   A.Value < B.Value
and B.Value < C.Value
union
select  A.Value,
    B.Value,
    C.Value,
    D.Value
from    T_VALUE A
    cross join T_VALUE B
    cross join T_VALUE C
    cross join T_VALUE D
where   A.Value < B.Value
and B.Value < C.Value
and C.Value < D.Value;
```

This did result in the following:

[image: screenshot]

```
V1  V2    V3    V4
AA  NULL  NULL  NULL
AA  AB    NULL  NULL
AA  AB    AC    NULL
AA  AB    AC    AD
AA  AB    AD    NULL
AA  AC    NULL  NULL
AA  AC    AD    NULL
AA  AD    NULL  NULL
AB  NULL  NULL  NULL
AB  AC    NULL  NULL
AB  AC    AD    NULL
AB  AD    NULL  NULL
AC  NULL  NULL  NULL
AC  AD    NULL  NULL
AD  NULL  NULL  NULL
```

I could also work with the values being stored in one field only. And I would also only need to build the table once. I can use this to reference items with possible combinations. I know that there will be a lot of possibilities.

Any ideas on how to generate a query to write this table in a simpler manner?

> Update:
>   I do need all possible combinations from AA - ZZ including "NULL" values as one option could also be 'AA' only or 'BC' only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a table with all possible combinations of 2 characters plus `NULL` ordered, so there are no duplicates.

The total number of pairs is 27 * 27 = 729 (because you have included `NULL`).  For four of them, there are 729 * 728 * 727 * 726 possibilities.   That comes to:  280,110,855,024.  Although it is possible to calculate and store that much data in a database, I do not see the utility.

Having said that, this code should do what you want:

```
with letters as (
      select  ascii('A') as l
      union all
      select  l + 1
      from letters
      where l < ascii('Z')
     ),
     l2 as (
      select char(c1.l) + char(c2.l) as pair, row_number() over (order by c1.l * 26 + c2.l) as n
      from letters c1 cross join
           letters c2
      union all
      select null, 0 as n
     )
select l2_1.pair, l2_2.pair, l2_3.pair l2_4.pair
from l2 l2_1 join
     l2 l2_2
     on l2_1.n < l2_2.n join
     l2 l2_3
     on l2_2.n < l2_3.n join
     l2 l2_4
     on l2_4.n < l2_3.n;
```

I do not recommend that anyone actually run this, unless they want to see the query break their system.

Comment: This seems to go in the right direction. But I probably would need 677 columns in that way. it could be all concatinated into one field. Why "only" four columns? I my example I did stop at AD hence AA - AD = 4 so I only worked with 4 columns

Comment: @Andreas . . . Three columns is at the limit of resonableness.  Six columns is probably at the outer limit of what *any* computer could do.

Comment: This is also the conclusion I came up with at first and was hopeing that maybe there is a simple way of a) generating and b) working with the table. Thank you Gordon

Comment: @Andreas . . . You might want to ask a *new* question, describing the actual problem that you have.  Perhaps your problem can be solved without generating all possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

```
with    list as
        (
        select  ascii('A') as i
        union all
        select  i + 1
        from    list
        where   i < ascii('Z')
        )
select  char(c1.i) + char(c2.i)
from    list c1
cross join
        list c2
union all
select  null
```

[Example at dbfiddle.co.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b00a4777251e16cf78d949378041cc8f)

Comment: Yes, this gives me a list of AA to ZZ, but not all possible combinations of them

Comment: This should result in AA to ZZ, including everything in between, like CE or ZB. What's missing from the result?

Comment: I don't think you got my question. In needd all combinations of AA-ZZ. not of a list of values from AA-ZZ. All possible combinations

Answer (score 0):

you could use some union and cross join

```
      select value as value1, null as value2, null as value3, null value4
      from table1
      union
      select  a.value, b.value, null, null 
      from table1 a
      cross join table1 b
      union
      select  a.value, b.value, c.value, null 
      from table1 a
      cross join table1 b
      cross join table1 c
      union
      select  a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value
      from table1 a
      cross join table1 b
      cross join table1 c
      cross join table1 d
```

for start with table1 you could use

```
  insert into table1
  select concat(t1.1value, t2.value)
  from (
    select  'A' value
    union 
    select 'B'
    union 
    select 'C'
    .....
    select 'Z'
  ) t1
  cross join (
    select  'A' value
    union 
    select 'B'
    union 
    select 'C'
    .....
    select 'Z'

    ) t2
```

or simple populate a table with A....Z

Comment: That is exactly what I currently am doing, but it is too complex for 650+ combinations.(AA - ZZ)

Comment: No, please look at the question. The cross join and union I am already doing and it is way too complex as I would need to write 650+ joins

Comment: looking to yor sample you smply need  a table with AA.... To ZZ .. answer updated  for first population too